# How to create a custom BSON Reader/Writer for nested and referenced documents?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am using `play2-reactivemongo` version 0.11.11 and `reactivemongo-play-json`. I have the following class:

```
case class Player(
                 id: Option[String],
                 profiles: List[Profile],
                 teams: List[Team],
                 created: Option[DateTime],
                 updated: Option[DateTime]
               ) extends Identity
```

The attribute `profiles` is represented as an array which contains elements of `Profile` documents (embedded). In contrast, the attribute `teams` represents an array of `_id` values. However, when working with instances of `Player` I want to handle a `List` of `Team` instances and not `_id` values. As a consequence, I think I need my own `BSONReader` and `BSONWriter` for this.

My code looks as follows:

```
implicit val PlayerBSONReader = new BSONDocumentReader[Player] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): Player =
      Player(
        doc.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id") map {
          _.stringify
        },

        // attributes 'profiles', 'teams' missing

        doc.getAs[BSONDateTime]("created").map(dt => new DateTime(dt.value)),
        doc.getAs[BSONDateTime]("updated").map(dt => new DateTime(dt.value))
      )
  }


 implicit val PlayerBSONWriter = new BSONDocumentWriter[Player] {
    def write(player: Player): BSONDocument =
      BSONDocument(
        "_id" -> player.id.map(BSONObjectID(_)),

        // attributes 'profiles', 'teams' missing   

        "created" -> player.created.map(date => BSONDateTime(date.getMillis)),
        "updated" -> BSONDateTime(DateTime.now.getMillis)
      )
  }
```

How can I set the attributes `profiles` and `teams`? Querying the database in a model is a bad practice, isn't it? But how can I set the instances when only having the `_id` values?

Answer (score 0):

There you need to make sure a `BSONReader` instance is available for any nested type (such as `Profile`).

The same requirement is recursive (e.g. if `Profile` itself has custom types as properties).

> I think you need to read more about the typeclass principle, to understand how it can work recursively, as for Play JSON `Reads`|`Writes`, or for BSON typeclasses.

Comment: Okay thanks, but this answers only part of my question. How can I set a list with instances of class `Team`, but only store their `_id` values as an array in the corresponding `User` document?